# String Handling in Java

Tags: java

I need to add one more predicate no_car(X),that will be true if the worker X has no cars,i.e,if we input a query ?:- no_car(X). the prolog should answer

Comment: Valid characters between words? Meanwhile, take a look the standard `sub_atom/5` predicate documentation.

Comment: Yeah, as usual: what have you tried, what are you familiar with? There are two types of IO in SWI-Prolog (Edinburgh-Style and ISO-Compliant) which one do you want to use?

Comment: You need to be more specific about where you get your input from. Standard input? A file? Or is it already a list of codes? A list of one-character atoms? Or, if you are using SWI-Prolog V7 and later, it could be a "string" (an SWI-Prolog 7 extension)?

Comment: @Boris I want to use standard input and then check last 2 letters of 4th words of each line of the input.

Comment: @AustinMullins: The Java background you deleted, is no noise in this context!

Comment: @false How does the fact that the OP is used to Java affect the problem or the best solution? The problem and the solution are both in Prolog.

Comment: @AustinMullins: This has to do with the declarative nature of Prolog. Yes, I should write a long answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So using only predicates available in the SWI-Prolog implementation, you can solve this in the following manner:

- Read first line, get last two characters of fourth word
- Read second line, do the same
- If they are the same, succeed and show the two characters

Implementation:

```
foo(X) :-
   last_two_chars_fourth_word(X),
   last_two_chars_fourth_word(X).
```

Reading a line and taking last two chars of fourth word:

- Read character codes from input
- Split into words separated by a single space
- Take the last two chars of the fourth word

Implementation:

```
last_two_chars_fourth_word(X) :-
    read_line_to_codes(user_input, Line),
    atom_codes(A, Line),
    atomic_list_concat(Words, ' ', A),
    nth1(4, Words, W),
    sub_atom(W, _Before, 2, 0, X).
```

If you want to read many lines you would have to adjust your `foo/1` to only stop at the end of input. See the SWI-Prolog documentation on details.

Comment: @Borris I tried your implementation,but it is just taking in first line of the input and printing last two letters of the 4th word of the first line.It is not taking input of the second line.

Comment: @noobcoder it is taking both. It then tries to unify them. If it succeeds, the X is unified with the _same two characters_ that appear at the end of the fourth word. If you want to have both, you need two different variables. See the other answer I wrote to your next question. You should also try and trace to see what is actually going on.

Comment: I am running the code with these arguments and this is what I am getting
    
        `?- foo(X).
         |: This is not aeoplane better be careful.
         X = ne.`
This is not taking in next line of input

Comment: @noobcoder there was a dot instead of a comma in my example above. I corrected it. Did you not get a "singleton variable" warning when you tried to compile?

Comment: @Yes I got singleton warning,so I had tried a comma also.But that also gave me this error the moment I enter 1st line
 
    `ERROR: foo/1: Undefined procedure:                     last_two_chars_foutrh_word/1
ERROR:   However, there are definitions for:
ERROR:         last_two_chars_fourth_word/1
   Exception: (7) last_two_chars_foutrh_word(ne) ? `
    
    `
Here ne are the last 2 letters of 4th word of my first line

Comment: @noobcoder there are typos in my answer, i guess you need to be able to spot them :) edited again

Comment: Oh sorry I missed that typo (foutrh instead of fourth).Thanks it works now:)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using SWI-Prolog, you can also use string-based functionality:

```
word_four_last_two(Two) :-
    read_string(user_input, "\n", "\r", _, String),
    split_string(String, " ", " ", [_,_,_,Word4|_]),
    sub_string(Word4, _, 2, 0, Two).
```

Comment: I tried your code with a few modification but it is giving singleton error.
`f(a) :-
   word(X).
   word(Y).

word(Two) :-
    read_string(user_input, "\n", "\r", _, String),
    split_string(String, " ", " ", [_,_,_,Word4|_]),
    sub_string(Word4, _, 2, 0, Two).`

This is what I tried.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution, it splits up the string into desired bits on reading, then writes it all out. Admittedly not the cleanest solution, but I hope you can see how the recursive reading is done.

```
read_line_into_reversed_words(Stream,Line):-
  read_line_helper(Stream,Line,[],[]).

read_line_helper(Stream,Line,WordAcc,Acc):-
    get_code(Stream,Char),
    ( Char = -1 -> false; 
        % End of file
      Char = 10 -> reverse(Line,Acc); 
        % Newline – Terminates HERE ↑
      Char = 32 -> read_line_helper(Stream,Line,[],[WordAcc|Acc]);
          % Space – one “word” is done.

     read_line_helper(Stream,Line,[Char|WordAcc],Acc)).

first_two_of_fourth_reversed(X,Result):-
    nth0(3,X,[Forelast,Last|_]),
    atom_codes(Result,[Last,Forelast]). % conversion into an Atom

write_result_for_stream_line(Stream):-
    read_line_into_reversed_words(Stream,Line),
    first_two_of_fourth_reversed(Line,X),
    write(X),nl.

write_the_result:-open(filename,read,Stream,[]),
   write_result_for_stream_line(Stream),
   write_result_for_stream_line(Stream).
```

Per request, here's a little rundown of what happens:

Strings in SWI-Prolog are usually lists of character codes. To get a feel for that, you can have a look at the predicate `atom_codes/2`:

```
?- A = "What".
A = [87, 104, 97, 116].


?- atom_codes('What', A).
A = [87, 104, 97, 116].
```

The I/O part: I have missed the predicate `read_string/5` which is good for reading lines. Thus I have written my own read_line predicate, that also splits into words. The `read_line_helper` recursively reads one character from the stream with `read_code/2` and reversely fills up the `WordAcc` variable. If a `" "` is detected, it puts the reversed word in front of the `Acc`(umulator) which will hold the reversed words of one reversed line. To extract the two characters, you could also do:

```
[_,_,_[Last,BeforeLast|RestOfFourthWord] = Line
```

Hope this helps a little.

I think this answer uses no SWI-Specific extensions, let me know if otherwise.

Comment: Thank you Patrick,but it kinda difficult for me to understand your code as I am new to prolog.Can you help me with my approach.
I was thinking to convert each line into lists(I don't know how)and then use this
[_ , _ , _ , X|tail]to get 4th word.Can you tell me how to convert each line to list and whether my approach is good?

Comment: @noobcoder: yes, you can use `[_,_,_,Word|_] = ListOfWords` to pick out the 4th element from a list.

Comment: @noobcoder: If you want to use built-in predicates, look at [jschimpf's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25983048/801553). I'll expand this a bit to make it more clear.